# nova-compute libvirt x86_64 emulator Error

Tags: linux-kvm, qemu, openstack, libvirt

I was trying to install openstackin Ubuntu12.04 server. I find that Nova-compute is not getting started and the error is the below. I followed some of the suggestions in various forums, but nothing worked.
It's a 64 bit kernel, Virtualization also enabled. Please help.

```
    # uname -a

    Linux hostnamekvm 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 16:19:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    # egrep -c ' lm ' /proc/cpuinfo
     4
```

These are the qemu/kvm packages that are installed.

```
    # dpkg --get-selections | grep qemu
    ipxe-qemu                   install
    qemu-common                 install
    qemu-keymaps                install
    qemu-kvm                    install
    qemu-system-common          install
    qemu-system-x86             install
    qemu-utils                  install

    # dpkg --get-selections | grep kvm
    nova-compute-kvm            install
    qemu-kvm                    install
```

I see that in my nova-compute.conf file, libvirt_type=kvm

```
    # kvm-ok
    INFO: /dev/kvm exists
    KVM acceleration can be used

    # lsmod | grep kvm
    kvm_intel             137899  0 
    kvm                   455932  1 kvm_intel
```

Checking the nova-compute.log messages

```
   # tail -f /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 179, in doit
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     result = proxy_call(self._autowrap, f, *args, **kwargs)
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 139, in proxy_call
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     rv = execute(f,*args,**kwargs)
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 77, in tworker
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     rv = meth(*args,**kwargs)
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 2884, in getVersion
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virConnectGetVersion() failed', conn=self)
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup libvirtError: internal error: Cannot find suitable emulator for x86_64
   2014-04-11 10:00:52.597 4758 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup
```

Checking libvertd.log messages,

```
   # tail -f /var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log
   2014-04-11 08:10:58.353+0000: 13213: error : virCommandWait:2348 : internal error: Child process (LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -help) unexpected exit status 127: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: undefined symbol: rbd_aio_discard

   2014-04-11 08:10:58.374+0000: 13213: error : virCommandWait:2348 : internal error: Child process (LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin /usr/bin/kvm-spice -help) unexpected exit status 127: W: kvm binary is deprecated, please use qemu-system-x86_64 instead
   qemu-system-x86_64: symbol lookup error: qemu-system-x86_64: undefined symbol: rbd_aio_discard

   2014-04-11 08:10:58.395+0000: 13213: error : virCommandWait:2348 : internal error: Child process (LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin /usr/bin/kvm -help) unexpected exit status 127: W: kvm binary is deprecated, please use qemu-system-x86_64 instead
   qemu-system-x86_64: symbol lookup error: qemu-system-x86_64: undefined symbol: rbd_aio_discard

   2014-04-11 08:10:58.402+0000: 13215: error : virQEMUCapsGetDefaultVersion:1699 : internal error: Cannot find suitable emulator for x86_64
   2014-04-11 08:10:58.440+0000: 13211: error : virNetSocketReadWire:1377 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error
```